# Rails 4 ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following form:

```
= semantic_form_for @contact, :url => club_contact_path(id: @club.id), :html => {:novalidate => false, :id => 'contact_club_form'} do |f|
              .sm-12.xl-5
              = f.input :club_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @club.id }
              = f.input :firstname, :required => true
              = f.input :lastname, :required => true
              = f.input :email, :required => true
              = f.input :telephone, :as => :phone, :required => false
              = f.input :question, :required => true, :as => :text, :input_html => {:rows => 5, :cols => 40}
              = f.action :submit, :button_html => {:class => 'btn btn-aqua', :value => 'Submit'}
```

Below I have added the `contact_params` method to the controller.
This errors out and tells me I have a `Rails::ForbiddenAttributesError`, but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :telephone, :question, :club_id)
  end
```

My model is the following:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email, :question, :telephone, :club_id
end
```

**EDIT: Added action**

```
def contact_club
    @contact = params[:contact]
    if Contact.create(@contact)
      byebug
      ContactMailer.send_contact_mail_to_club(@contact)
      render :nothing => true
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Update your create action and console log in question

Comment: `if Contact.create(@contact)` results in the `ForbiddenAttributesError`, I set `@contact = params[:contact]`.
I don't know where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contact_params method wraps your parameters in a class that Rails now expects when creating or saving a new object. Right now you're accessing it directly which you can't do anymore if you are using strong parameters. You want to pass contact_params in to the Contact.new or Contact.create methods.

Also I was confused by your setting @contact = params[:contact], I think you are trying to get an instance of the Contact model and then pass that to the mailer. Is that correct? If so the following snippet should be closer to what you're looking for.

```
def contact_club
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    byebug
    ContactMailer.send_contact_mail_to_club(@contact)
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass permitted params in your create action not direct params. So try change `@contact` to `contact_params` in your create call.

In your current code you are not passing right params. So try change your code like below.

```
def contact_club
  @contact = params[:contact]
  if Contact.create(contact_params)
    byebug
    ContactMailer.send_contact_mail_to_club(@contact)
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```